# Python - Unable to split lines from a txt file into words

Tags: python, list, file-io, split

My goal is to open a file and split it into unique words and display that list (along with a number count). I think I have to split the file into lines and then split those lines into words and add it all into a list.

The problem is that if my program will run in an infinite loop and not display any results, or it will only read a single line and then stop. The file being read is The Gettysburg Address.

```
def uniquify( splitz, uniqueWords, lineNum ):
for word in splitz:
    word = word.lower()        
    if word not in uniqueWords:
        uniqueWords.append( word )

def conjunctionFunction():

    uniqueWords = []

    with open(r'C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Address.txt') as f :
        getty = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
    lineNum = 0
    lines = getty[lineNum]
    getty.append("\n")
    while lineNum < 20 :
        splitz = lines.split()
        lineNum += 1

        uniquify( splitz, uniqueWords, lineNum )
    print( uniqueWords )


conjunctionFunction()
```

Comment: is your indentation correct or is it just a copy/paste issue while you were creating the question here ?

Comment: Why is lineNum needed as a parameter for function uniquify?

Comment: I am using lineNum in order to reference each line in the file. For the uniquify function, I was experimenting with putting lineNum += 1 in the uniquify function along with the if statement.

Comment: You're not advancing your while loop, you just keep pasting the same line until the counter hits 20

Comment: @turbo Just fixed it after realizing that simple mistake, thanks!

Comment: I think the tabbing of your code got messed up when you pasted it, so I'm not sure exactly what you're doing. @HappyCry's answer might work, try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your current code, the line:

```
lines = getty[lineNum]
```

should be moved within the while loop.

Comment: @user3010284 This is the correct answer, which is why I upvoted it, but you should take a look at my answer, too.  You're complicating this task.

Answer (score 1):

You figured out what's wrong with your code, but nonetheless, I would do this slightly differently.  Since you need to keep track of the number of unique words and their counts, you should use a dictionary for this task:

```
wordHash = {}

with open('C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Address.txt', 'r') as f :
    for line in f:
       line = line.rstrip().lower()

       for word in line:
            if word not in wordHash:
                wordHash[word] = 1

            else: 
                wordHash[word] += 1

print wordHash
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def splitData(filename):
    return [words for words in open(filename).reads().split()]
```

Easiest way to split a file into words :)

Answer (score 0):

Assume `inp` is retrived from a file

```
inp = """Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense."""


data = inp.splitlines()

print data

_d = {}

for line in data:
    word_lst = line.split()
    for word in word_lst:
        if word in _d:
            _d[word] += 1
        else:
            _d[word] = 1

print _d.keys()
```

Output

```
['Beautiful', 'Flat', 'Simple', 'is', 'dense.', 'Explicit', 'better', 'nested.', 'Complex', 'ugly.', 'Sparse', 'implicit.', 'complex.', 'than', 'complicated.']
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

import pprint
import collections

def genwords(file_):
    for line in file_:
        for word in line.split():
            yield word

def main():
    with open('gettysburg.txt', 'r') as file_:
        result = collections.Counter(genwords(file_))

    pprint.pprint(result)

main()
```

...but you could use re.findall to deal with punctuation better, instead of string.split.